# How to save one hot encoded model and predict new unencoded data using scikitlearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

My dataset contains 3 categorical features and I used one hot encoding to change it to binary format and all went fine. But when I want to save that trained model and predict new raw data, the inputted is not encoded as I expected and result in error.

```
combined_df_raw2= pd.concat([train_x_raw,unknown_test_df])
combined_df2 = pd.get_dummies(combined_df_raw2, columns=nominal_cols, 
drop_first=True)

encoded_unknown_df = combined_df2[len(train_x_raw):]

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=17)
classifier.fit(train_x_raw, train_Y)

pred_y = classifier.predict(encoded_unknown_df)

#here I use joblib to save my model and load it again
joblib.dump(classifier, 'savedmodel')
imported_model = joblib.load('savedmodel')

#here I input unencoded raw data for predict and got error that cannot             
convert 'tcp' to float, means that it is not encoded 

imported_model.predict([0,'tcp','vmnet','REJ',0,0,0,23])
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'tcp'

Comment: [sklearn OHE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) does the encoding for you.. In case of `dummies` you need to maintain a map for test data.

Comment: @rock321987 exactly that was what I looking for. There are some complexities where I could not use OHE for the encoding. Can you please tell me how to maintain a map for test data. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will point to a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538125/how-preprocessing-unseen-data-with-onehotencoder-and-labelencoder-so-that-matchs?rq=1)

Comment: This link uses OHE I want to maintain a map using get.dummies for future encoding!

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070201/pandas-handle-unseen-data-in-test)

Answer (score 4):

The model is trained after encoding the categorical variable, hence, the input has to be given after applying 'onehot encoding' to respective variables. Example: one of the column is titeled as "Country" and you have three different values across the dataset viz. ['India', Israel', 'France'], now you have applied OneHotEncoding(Probably after LabelEncoder) on the country column, then you train your model, save it do whatever other stuff you want!

Now the question is, you get input error when you directly give input without changing it to the format on which the model was trained. Hence, we will always want to preprocess the input before we give it to model. The most common way in my knowledge is to use Pipeline.

```
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('ohe', OneHotEncoder()),('SVM', 
        DecisionTreeClassifier())]
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps) # You need to save this pipeline via joblib
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Incase, you don't want to use Pipeline, you can anyways use OneHotEncode on specific column/s and then use predict!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

Use `fit()` followed by `transform()`, that way you can pickle your one hot encoder after you have fit it.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)
```

Then lets pickle your encoder, you could use other ways of persisting the encoder. Check out, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

```
import pickle
with open('encoder.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(enc, f)
```

Now when you have new data to predict, you must first go through the entire pre-processing pipeline you did for your training data. In this case the encoder. Let's load it back,

```
with open('encoder.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    enc = pickle.loads(f)
```

Once you have it loaded, you just need to transform the new data.

```
enc.transform(new_data)
```

To know more about pickle, https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Although this does the trick, joblib is a good way to go too. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: Suppose if the level is not present in the incoming new data. Still will the method work?

Comment: Nope only the words given to fit are encoded during a transform. Note if there are other words in your test dataset that would be a bigger issue. For ex, say the training dataset only contains 'male' and 'female' but the test dataset also contains 'other'. This is unseen data for your model. And the model will perform poorly. Also OHE will not work, since the no of features between train and test dataset would vary.

Answer (score 0):

@chintan then e.g for the upcoming raw data, if you convert the categorial variable having only one instance then it will make only one extra column, while before for the categorical column you had, vod be having like 500 columns. so it wont match again. 
take an example of currencies, one instance is coming have INR only, even if you do the encoding, it will convert it into a column,
but before you have columns for all the curruncies in the world

Comment: This a comment, not the answer